# Turning props into state after initialisation with GetDerivedStateFromProps?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have the following, super-simple Component:

```
export default class Editor extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { field: "Some Initial Text" };

    this.handleChangeField = this.handleChangeField.bind(this);
  }

  handleChangeField(e) {
    this.setState({field: e.target.value});
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <input type="text" name="word" value={this.state.field} onChange={this.handleChangeField} />
          {this.state.field}
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

It just has a field. The field can be edited by the user. Depending on what the user clicks on in a sibling-component, the above component will receive a prop called `fieldValue` which will then be what's shown in the input field. Since the user should be able to edit this input field, I cannot simply put the prop into the input-field directly, but use state. So I initialise the components state from the prop.

However, this prop might change even after the component is initialised. That is, it will *not only be an initial value*, but might change during runtime, depending on what the user clicks on in the sibling-components.

How would I solve something like this in React 16.3, with `ComponentWillReceiveProps` being deprecated? I have tried looking into `GetDerivedStateFromProps`, but I don't fully understand how to use it.

Comment: This might help: https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html#updating-state-based-on-props

Comment: Why not just set the state in the constructor?

Comment: @Keith because the constructor will not be called every single time the props change. And the props might change during the lifetime of the component.

Comment: I would advise reading this: https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't go for trying to sync [uncontrolled component with controlled component](https://reactjs.org/docs/glossary.html#controlled-vs-uncontrolled-components), as the logic can get crazy when the component scales.

With that said, if  you really want to track prop changes and update state accordingly you could use [componentDidUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) but make sure you got some valid conditions before updating the state.

Here is a running example:

```js
class Editor extends React.Component {

  state = { field: this.props.defaultValue };

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    const { defaultValue } = this.props;
    if (prevProps.defaultValue !== defaultValue) {
      this.setState({ field: defaultValue });
    }
  }

  handleChangeField = (e) => {
    this.setState({ field: e.target.value });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" name="word" value={this.state.field} onChange={this.handleChangeField} />
        {this.props.defaultValue}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  state = { value: 'A default value' }

  handleChange = ({ target }) => this.setState({ value: target.value })

  render() {
    const { value } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>App </h3>
        <input type="text" value={value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        <hr />
        <h3>Editor</h3>
        <Editor defaultValue={value} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

It's super simple, here is a prototype that should work:

```
export default class Editor extends Component {
  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    // You need to return object that will be used to fill the state, not manipulate the state itself
    return {
      field: state.field
    }
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.handleChangeField = this.handleChangeField.bind(this);
  }

  handleChangeField(e) {
    this.setState({field: e.target.value});
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <input type="text" name="word" value={this.state.field} onChange={this.handleChangeField} />
          {this.state.field}
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```